# Define a constant BIGNUM in OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, bignum

Is there a way to define a constant of type BIGNUM* and value `2^512` in C that would be the equivalent of Java:

```
private static final BigInteger THRESHOLD = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(512);
```

In a local scope I achieve this by doing the following:

```
BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();

BIGNUM *two = BN_new();
BN_set_word(two, 2);

BIGNUM *pow = BN_new();
BN_set_word(pow, 512);

BIGNUM * threshold = BN_new();
BN_exp(threshold, two, pow, ctx);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

In OpenSSL 1.0.2/1.0.1 this is possible (caveat: code completely untested!)

```
/*
 * I made up the numbers...too lazy to figure out what the real ones are!
 * Note that, the BN_ULONG values here are in little endian form,
 * so this represents:
 * D3FBF564FEB008A3
 */
#if BN_BITS2 == 64
static const BN_ULONG data[] = {
    0xA308B0FE64F5FBD3ULL
};
#else
static const BN_ULONG data[] = {
    0x64F5FBD3, 0xA308B0FE
};
#endif

static const BIGNUM threshold = {
    (BN_ULONG *) data,
    sizeof(data)/sizeof(BN_ULONG),
    sizeof(data)/sizeof(BN_ULONG),
    0,
    BN_FLG_STATIC_DATA
};
```

In OpenSSL 1.1.0 (not yet released) things are not so easy. For very good reasons the BIGNUM structure has been made opaque so you can no longer statically initialise the data.

You *can* do something like this:

```
static CRYPTO_ONCE threshold_once = CRYPTO_ONCE_STATIC_INIT;
static BIGNUM *threshold = NULL;

static void thresholdcleanup(void)
{
    BN_free(threshold);
}
static void thresholdinit(void)
{
    threshold = BN_new();
    /* Do stuff to set threshold to the right value */
    OPENSSL_atexit(thresholdcleanup);
}

static void my_func(void)
{
    CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once(&threshold_once, threshholdinit);

    /* Use threshold here */
}
```